# Proof that a sequence converges pointwisely, but not uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have the following task in my homework:

We consider a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ given by $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $f_n(x) = 1 - χ_{[-n,n]}(x)$ converges pointwisely, but not uniformly, to 0.

Here, the function $χ_{[-n,n]}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by

$$χ_{[-n,n]}(x) = \begin{cases} 1\text{ if } x \in [-n,n] \\ 0 \text{ else}. \end{cases} $$

So... this confuses me. First and foremost, this only converges to 0 when $χ_{[-n,n]}(x)$ is 1 and thus when x is only between -n and n, but outside of those bounds, so for x larger than n, I do not see how this is supposed to converge to 0 when $χ_{[-n,n]}(x)$ is 0 too... Perhaps I just don't fully understand the definition of pointwise and uniform convergence, but I don't see how this is supposed to converge to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointwise convergence of the sequence $f_n$ to $f$ works as follows:

$$ \forall x:\ \lim_{n\to\infty} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$$

and uniform convergence works differently. In that type of convergence, it is not looking at a single point but it is looking at all points at the same time, i.e.,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0. $$

In your case, it works that for all $x$, $f_n(x) \to 0$. Since for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we can find an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x| \leq n$. Hence for $m\geq n$, we have $f_m(x) = 0$, which implies that the limit equals $0$.

As you already suggested, this $n$ does not work for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ at the same time. Indeed, for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$ \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - 0| = 1, $$
which thus does not converge to $0$.

I think that the definition of the types of convergence should be more clear now. If you have any questions, feel free to ask them!

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped!

Comment: I hope that won't come across as annoying, but the task then continues with $f_n(x) = (1 - χ_{[-n,n]}(x))e^{-|x|}$ and says that I have to prove that it converges uniformly. I know that $e^{-|x|}$ converges to 0 and has its maximum at $x=0$, but I'm not sure I can formulate the proof properly. I don't need a detailed explanation, a hint on how I should start should suffice. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I will give you a hint. To prove uniform convergence you have to split $\mathbb{R}$ up into a part that is 'large' and a part that is 'small'. The small part you can control by the structure of this indicator function and the large part you can control by $e^{-x}$.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&-n\leq x\leq n\\
1&x<-n\lor x>n
\end{cases}$$
hence for all $x$ you have $f_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, that's $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$.
On the other hand, note that for all $n\in\Bbb N$ you have
$$\sup_{\Bbb R}|f_n|=1$$
hence $\sup_{\Bbb R}|f_n|\not\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
Consequently, you have not uniform convergence (that's convergence with respect to the uniform metric) to $0$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense now!